# Emphasize labels in a graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, graphs

I've got a graph with nodes and arcs between them. Then I added labels to the nodes.

My problem now: The labels are partially unreadable because the arcs disturb.

Do I have an opportunity to highlight the labels, that they are better readable. Like a background color or something like that? What is the common solution for this problem?

I tried to change the text color but this isn't enough to solve the problem.

Edit: example code!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=18pt, inner sep=0pt]
    \def \x{2}
    \def \y{1.5}
    \draw (1 * \x, 0 * \y) node (leer) [draw=green, label=90:5] {$\emptyset$};
    \draw (1 * \x,-1 * \y) node (b) [draw=green, label=90:{1,2,3}] {b};
    \draw [->]  (leer) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In this example, you can barely read the "2". How can I emphasize the "1,2,3"-String to improve die readability!

Now dynamically:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcount\incount
\def\tin#1#2{\incount=0\relax\edef\marshal{\noexpand\TIn#1@@;#2@@;}\marshal}
\def\TIn#1#2;#3#4;{%
  \ifx#1@%   
    \ifx#3@%
      \incount=\ifnum0>\incount-\fi\incount%
      \let\next=\relax%
    \else%
      \advance\incount by-1%
      \def\next{\TIn#1#2;#4;}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \def\test##1#1##2##3?{\ifx##2*\else\advance\incount by1\fi}%
    \test#3#4;#1**?%
    \def\next{\TIn#2;#3#4;}%
  \fi%
  \next%      
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[declare function={nchoosek(\n,\k)=\n!/(\k!*(\n-\k)!);}, x=1.5cm,y=2.5cm,
NULL/.style={fill=green!30, label=90:{1,2,3,4,5}},
A/.style={fill=green!30, label=90:{1,3,4,5}},
B/.style={fill=green!30, label=90:{1,3,5}},
C/.style={fill=green!30, label=90:{1,2,4,5}},
D/.style={fill=red!30, label=90:{2,5}},
E/.style={fill=green!30, label=90:{1,3,5}},
]

\foreach \R [count=\y from 0, evaluate={\s=nchoosek(5,\y);}, remember=\R as \r] in {
   {NULL},
   {A,B,C,D,E}}
   \foreach \C [count=\x from 0] in \R {   
     \node [circle, draw, anchor=base, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.75cm, \C/.try]
       (\C) at (-\s/2+\x,-\y+1) {\C};       
      \foreach \c in \r {
        \tin{\c}{\C}
        \ifnum\incount=1
          \draw (\c.south) -- (\C.north);
        \fi
     }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about using `fill=white`? An MWE would be very helpful...

Comment: I've edited my post to add example code! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, Jake! Now you have a minimal example that should work!

Comment: @user2438518: Thanks for editing, now it's a perfect MWE (minimal working example)!

Comment: You're welcome! Now I'm waiting for an answer.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insert the label on a node inside the segment line. Remove the label `1,2,3` from node `(b)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=18pt, inner sep=0pt]
    \def \x{2}
    \def \y{1.75} %% edited here for better view
    \draw (1 * \x, 0 * \y) node (leer) [draw=green, label=90:5] {$\emptyset$};
    \draw (1 * \x,-1 * \y) node (b) [draw=green] {b};
    \draw [->]  (leer) --node[fill=white,draw=white,rectangle]{1,2,3} (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit:** Based on the edited post, you can make use of the same trick.
**Note:** Fixed typo which prevented code from compiling

Load the `backgrounds` library with `\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}`. Then define a style for the nodes with `every label/.style={fill=white,rectangle,inner sep=2pt}`. Finally, insert the segment lines connecting the nodes inside the background layer.

See the code with comments:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
 every label/.style={fill=white,rectangle,inner sep=2pt},  %% here is new
 declare function={nchoosek(\n,\k)=\n!/(\k!*(\n-\k)!);},
 x=1.75cm,y=2.5cm,  %% changed x value for better view
NULL/.style={fill=green!30, label=90:{1,2,3,4,5}},
A/.style={fill=green!30, label=90:{1,3,4,5}},
B/.style={fill=green!30, label=90:{1,3,5}},
C/.style={fill=green!30, label=90:{1,2,4,5}},
D/.style={fill=red!30, label={90:{2,5}}},
E/.style={fill=green!30, label=90:{1,3,5}},
]

\foreach \R [count=\y from 0, evaluate={\s=nchoosek(5,\y);}, remember=\R as \r] in {
   {NULL},
   {A,B,C,D,E}}
   \foreach \C [count=\x from 0] in \R {   
     \node [circle, draw, anchor=base, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.75cm, \C/.try]
       (\C) at (-\s/2+\x,-\y+1) {\C};       
      \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}  %% here is new
      \foreach \c in \r {
        \in{\c}{\C}
        \ifnum\incount=1
          \draw (\c.south) -- (\C.north);
        \fi
     }
      \end{pgfonlayer}                %% here is new
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Sigur! Thank you for your help!! I had to change my graph and now I've had to make it dynamically. I edited the MWE in my prior post! Could you help me once again?? That would be very nice!! thanks a lot!